# How to format output array correctly in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to produce an array that is formatted as follows:

```
Array(  
Array([100000116287110]=>  
Array([name] => Bryce [image] => abcd.png))  
Array([100003019827186]=>  
Array([name] => Ross [image] => defg.png))  
)
```

The data to produce the array comes from 2 different sources and is fed to a function.

The function call is `lookupUserData($a, array(“name”, “image”))`  //this has been set up so other details from the user table can be called simply by adding the field name in the array. 
$a is formated as `$a = “100000116287110,100003019827186”`

The current code I am using for the function is as follows:

```
function lookupUserData($f,$u)
{
$f = explode(",",$f); //user id from string – converts string to array ([0] =>100000116287110 [1] =>100003019827186)
$u = implode(",",$u); //fields to extract – converts array(“name”,”image”) to name,image
$r=array(); //define results array`
$nr = count($f); //count number of ids to process
for($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) { //process each id in $f array
$r[]=$f[$i];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT {$u} FROM users where id ={$f[$i]}"); //query user table
$val= mysql_fetch_assoc($res); //return requested fields ($u) from user table
array_push($r, $val); //add values to array $r
}
print_r ($r); //check array output – testing only
return $r; //return array for processing
}
```

This however returns the result as follows:

```
Array(  
Array([0]=>[100000116287110]  
Array([name] => Bryce [image] => abcd.png))  
Array([1]=>[100003019827186]  
Array([name] => Ross [image] => defg.png))  
)
```

I know I have missed something simple but just cannot seem to get this right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$r= array();
for($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) { //process each id in $f array

 $res = mysql_query("SELECT {$u} FROM users where id ={$f[$i]}"); //query user table
 $val= mysql_fetch_assoc($res); //return requested fields ($u) from user table
 $r[$f[$i]] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I knew it was a simple thing just could not see it (Think I need to have a refresher in array basics!)